# Can't run page specific javascript pack when using Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, turbolinks, webpacker

I'm using Rails 5.1 and webpacker with Vue.js.

Instead of using conditionals to test if an element is on a page and then proceed to mount a vue app specific to a certain page, I would like to load a specific javascript pack tag in a specific page. The problem is that when I'm on a page that hasn't loaded the script pack and then travel to the page that does load it, the turbolinks load event is dispatched **before** my script evaluates, so the code for mounting the Vue app never runs because it depends on the `turbolinks:load` event.

My question is basically, is mounting multiple Vue apps based on conditionals (which are based on the current page) inside one javascript pack the best way? It seems like it shouldn't be because the file size would be larger than necessary.

On the other hand, is it possible load a script using Turbolinks and have it run before `turbolinks:load` is dispatched?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe this will help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178315/how-to-fix-didnt-work-redirect-by-turbolinks-in-ruby-on-rails-with-vue-js/59159352#59159352](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178315/how-to-fix-didnt-work-redirect-by-turbolinks-in-ruby-on-rails-with-vue-js/59159352#59159352)