# How to fix 'didn't work redirect by Turbolinks' in Ruby on Rails with Vue.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, turbolinks

In my sign in page, didn't work redirect by Turbolinks.
This page use form for sign in. After posting form correct information, browser end up going to original page.

I'm implementing sign in page with `Ruby on Rails` and `Vue.js`.
In loading, I use `Turbolinks`, so I did `Vue.js` plugin `vue-turbolinks`, too.

Rails: 5.2.2
Ruby: 2.5.1
Turbolinks: 5
vue-turbolinks: 2.0.4
webpacker: 3.5

user_controller.rb

```
# coding: utf-8
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "registing user data"
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      flash[:danger] = "invalid info"
      redirect_to '/signup'
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:user_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add</h1>
</div>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'new' %>
<div>
```

new.vue

```
<template>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="text" v-model="username" placeholder="username">
    <input type="text" v-model="email" placeholder="email">
    <input type="password" v-model="password" placeholder="password">
    <input type="password" v-model="password_confirm" placeholder="password(confirm)">
    <button type="submit" v-on:click="sendForm">send</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

const token = document.getElementsByName("csrf-token")[0].getAttribute("content");
axios.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRF-Token"] = token;
axios.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
axios.defaults.headers.common["charset"] = "utf-8";
axios.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      password_confirm: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendForm: function(e){
      axios.post("/signup", {
        "user": {
          "user_name": this.username,
          "email": this.email,
          "password": this.password,
          "password_confirmation": this.password_confirm,
        }
      })
      .then(response => { 
      })
      .catch(response => {
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

new.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import New from '../new.vue';
import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks';

Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter);

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    const el = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('new'));
    const new_ = new Vue({
        el,
        render: h => h(New)
    });

    console.log('/new page');
});
```

I expect the after loading, browser go to root page in correct registing.

Answer (score 0):

/vueturbo.js

```
 if (typeof(Vueturbo) === 'undefined') {
       Vueturbo = {};
    }

    Vueturbo.Dispatcher = function() {
       this.dispatch = function() {
          var elements = $('.sjs');
          var cls, meth;

          $(elements).each(function (index, element) {
             tokens  = $(element).attr('data-cls').split('.');
             meth    = $(element).attr('data-method') || 'fire';
             context = window;

             $(tokens).each(function(tidx, token) {
                context = context[token];
             });

             cls = new (context)();
             cls[meth]();
          });
       };

       this.turbolinks = function() {
          var ref = this;
          document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
            ref.dispatch();
          });
       };
    };
```

insert the tag and dispatcher callings in templates
../views/layouts/public.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<script charset="utf-8">(new Vueturbo.Dispatcher()).turbolinks();</script>
...
<%= yield %>
...
```

insert the tag calling the js that you want
../views/public/new.html.erb

```
<%= hidden_field_tag nil, 'new', class: 'sjs', 'data-cls': 'Vueturbo.new' %>
```

/new.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import New from '../new.vue';
import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks';

Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter);

Vueturbo.new = function() {
  this.fire = function() {
    const el = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('new'));
    const new_ = new Vue({
        el,
        render: h => h(New)
    });
  }
}
```